# Need to extract out all cells in a 2-D array (256x256) which falls in sector with center at origin and label all other cells as zero

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a 2-d 256x256 array and now, given player is at center, I need to extract a FOV (Field Of View) that is visible to the player.
For example if player is looking at right with FOV as 180 then I would need a 256x256-matrix whose cells in right half submatrix (256x128) remain same, while the left half cells are all made zero. (radius can be taken infinity as curvature is not needed, so we finally get a triangle to deal with)

Comment: First find a general inequality in terms of the angle the player is facing. Then for a particular angle, set everything coordinate that does not satisfy the inequality to 0.

Comment: First find cells that make up your edges (for exmaple using Bresenham's algorithm), than fill everything above/below the lines (for your example case) - you can be sure that the other half of the map will be zeroed out

Comment: Thank you. Can I know the technique to make the edge in the array. As in, the origin vertex is (128,128) and the final point depends on fov and line of sight.